# Sum of array items - php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add up the sum of items in an array.

Here is a copy of some data from the array.

```
$hours = Array ( 
[3] => 
    Array (
        [2014-09-15] => Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [21] => 2 [22] => 2 [23] => 2 [24] => 2 )
        [2014-09-16] => Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 ) 
        [2014-09-17] => Array ( [9] => 2 [10] => 2 [11] => 2 [12] => 2 [13] => 2 [14] => 2 [15] => 2 [16] => 2 ) 
        [2014-09-19] => Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 [21] => 1 [22] => 1 [23] => 1 [24] => 1 ) 
    )
 )
```

And here is the code I am using to add it together.

```
$week_start_date = "2014-09-15";

for ( $i = 0; $i < 7; $i++ ) {
    $total_hours_day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($week_start_date . "+ " . $i . " days"));
    $total_hours = array();
    foreach ( $hours as $the_user_id => $other_data1 ) {
        foreach ( $hours[$the_user_id][$total_hours_day] as $the_nth_hour => $other_data3 ){
            $total_hours[$the_nth_hour]++;
        }
    }
    echo $total_hours_day
    echo "<br />" . $total_hours["1"] . $total_hours["2"] . $total_hours["3"] . $total_hours["4"];
    echo "<br />" . $total_hours["5"] . $total_hours["6"] . $total_hours["7"] . $total_hours["8"];
    echo "<br />" . $total_hours["9"] . $total_hours["10"] . $total_hours["11"] . $total_hours["12"];
    echo "<br />" . $total_hours["13"] . $total_hours["14"] . $total_hours["15"] . $total_hours["16"];
    echo "<br />" . $total_hours["17"] . $total_hours["18"] . $total_hours["19"] . $total_hours["20"];
    echo "<br />" . $total_hours["21"] . $total_hours["22"] . $total_hours["23"] . $total_hours["24"];

}
```

Is there a neater way to add this up?

I also seem to missing the $total_hours["24"] on my last set of numbers for

---

Comment: Have you tried [array_sum($arr)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)?

Comment: No, I didn't want to add up the value of the data. I want to know how many data entires there are.

Comment: You mean how many entries per date?

Comment: Kind of @Edper , how many entries per hour per day is want I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$hours = Array ( 
[3] => 
    Array (
        [2014-09-15] => Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [21] => 2 [22] => 2 [23] => 2 [24] => 2 )
        [2014-09-16] => Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 ) 
        [2014-09-17] => Array ( [9] => 2 [10] => 2 [11] => 2 [12] => 2 [13] => 2 [14] => 2 [15] => 2 [16] => 2 ) 
        [2014-09-19] => Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 [7] => 1 [8] => 1 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 [11] => 1 [12] => 1 [13] => 1 [14] => 1 [15] => 1 [16] => 1 [17] => 1 [18] => 1 [19] => 1 [20] => 1 [21] => 1 [22] => 1 [23] => 1 [24] => 1 ) 
    )
 )

$total_hours = array();
$user_id = 3;

foreach($hours[$user_id] as $date => $work_hours){
   $total_hours[$user_id][$date] = array_sum($hours[$user_id][$date]);
}

print_r($total_hours);
```

Comment: I have more than 1 user that I need to add the hours for. Otherwise this would work. So I want to have the sum of each hour of all users.